# Tensorflow Federated: given a model train it with 2 different datsets and calcaulate euclidian distance between these models

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-federated

I have a next word prediction model based on federated learning with tensorflow model. My server need to calculate the distance between the model weigtht I receive in each round. Do you have any idea how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Get the model weights using model.get_weights() for each model,

Then make them as a tensor. For example

```
model1_weights= model1.get_weights()
model2_weights= model2.get_weights()

weights= tf.constant([[model1_weights],[model2_weights]])
```

Then you can find the euclidean distance using

```
tf.math.reduce_euclidean_norm(x)
```

For more details you can refer to this [gist](https://gist.github.com/kiransair/9557b4265bc55e2ef07290acc79dee62). Thank You.